# How to Build Dynamic Query

Tags: mysql

Actually i am building an app where i am providing multiple check boxes to the customer such as whether he want up to 5% discount or he want 10% to 20% discount or he want 20% to 30% discount. In this case i want to fire a query for 5%,10-20%,20-30% discounts. Customer can either select one of the above options or he can select all options. How should I Build my query for his selection in phpMyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$dicsount= $_GET['dicsount'];
$price= $_GET['price'];
$name= $_GET['name'];

if($dicsount!=""){
    $where[] = " `dicsount` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($dicsount)."'";
}
if($price!=""){
    $where[] = " `price` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."'";
}
if($name!=""){
    $where[] = " `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
}
$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $where);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `$where_clause` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
```